# Why is my site text dancing when I highlight it? CSS ::selection

Tags: css, google-chrome, selection

Using Chrome, highlight any of the text on [my site](http://ecologyartisan.staging.wpengine.com/) and it crosses over itself and mumble jumbles.

I've got the following in my SASS/CSS file:

```
// ::selection
*::-moz-selection {
  color: $mulberry;
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% $keylime;
}

*::selection {
    color: $mulberry; 
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% $keylime;
}
```

I first tried it without the asterisk wildcards, but no luck, still does the shimmy-shake dance. When I remove it, it's fine. Any tips greatly appreciated as to why Chrome might be doing this. Not happening in Safari or Firefox.

Comment: Did you try using -webkit- (since that's Chrome's vendor code). For example, -webkit-selection

Comment: No @AdibBehjat, I didn't, but removing the ligatures helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some funky font-styles in there, This is what is causing the problem:

`-webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga", "dlig"`

If you remove that CSS rule, the problem goes away.